# Error with generate and downloading MVC view to PDF function (Itext - System IO.IO this document has no pages)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, methods

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and not that good with coding. I'm trying to download my returned list from view as a PDF document

The exact error I get is:

> System.IO.IOException
> HResult=0x80131620
> The document has no pages.
> Source=itextsharp
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree()
> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()
> at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
> at iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()

[My controller with function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXpqo.png)

[My view html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4t0t.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read _[How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)_.

Comment: Hi, Please post your code as a text instead of using images, [why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your jquery and your html, you are not passing any values into your div, your table is also not in your div. Thus jquery is pulling nothing, that means that your stream is getting no bytes.